# Laravel: Llenar select desde tabla y seleccionar el valor obtenido segun formulario de edición

Tags: sql, laravel, blade

Seguramente sea algo sencillo y tengo la idea clara pero seguro sea la sintaxis que estoy usando.

Tengo estas dos tablas:

- CLIENTES:
- id
- rut
- nombre
- telefono

Y

- YEGUAS:
- id
- cliente_id (para relacionar con la tabla CLIENTES)
- nombre
- edad

Estoy en un dashboard con un listado de Yeguas y alli quiero editar una, en la vista, el botón editar es así:

```
<a href="{{ url('/edit_yegua/') }}/{{$yegua->id}}" class="text-success mr-2">
    <i class="nav-icon i-Pen-2 font-weight-bold"></i>
</a>
```

En el controller tengo esto:

```
use App\Cliente;
use App\Yegua;
use Auth;

class YeguasController extends Controller
{
public function edit_yegua($id){
   $yegua = Yegua::where('id', $id)->first();
   $cliente = Cliente::where('client_id', $client_id)->first();
   return view('app.yeguas.edit_yegua',compact('yegua'));
}

public function edit_yegua_action(Request $request){
    Yegua::where('id',$request->id)->update(
    array(
        'nombre' => $request->nombre_yegua,
        'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'color' => $request->color,
        'aptitud' => $request->aptitud,
        'ano_nacimiento' => $request->ano_nacimiento,
        'condicion_corporal' => $request->condicion_corporal,
        'estado_reproductivo' => $request->estado_reproductivo,
        'numero_gestaciones' => $request->numero_gestaciones,
        'fecha_parto' => $request->fecha_parto,
        'historial_clinico' => $request->historial_clinico,
        'resultado_biopsia' => $request->resultado_biopsia,
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'color' => $request->color,
        'aptitud' => $request->aptitud
    ));

   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua editada!");
}
}
```

Y en la vista que tiene el formulario para editar quiero llenar un select que muestre todos los clientes de la tabla y a su vez que deje seleccionado el que tiene esa Yegua. Acá el código:

```
<select class="form-control" id="client_id" name="client_id" required>
<option value="">Seleccione un Cliente</option>
    @foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
        <option value="{{$cliente->id}}" @if($cliente->id===$client_id) selected='selected' @endif>
            {{$cliente->nombre}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Seguramente es algo muy básico pero esto que coloco hasta el momento me sigue dando infinidad de errores. Básicamente mis errores comienzan en el controlador, aun no domino el paso de variables y como obtenerlos para validarlos con las tablas en este caso asi como obtuve el $id de Yegua y buscar el Ciente con el $cliente_id.

Gracias...

Comment: Gracias amigo... con ambos consejos pude solucionar. Sólo que no me deja seleccionado el Cliente correspondiente a la Yegua en el <select>... Creo que tengo algo mal acá: <option value="{{$cliente->id}}" @if($cliente->id===$yegua->cliente_id) selected='selected' @endif>

Comment: Exacto, es $client_id, lo cambie y funcionó, Muchas gracias... Ahora, si tengo otro <select> con una lista de la condición corporal y tambien necesito que quede seleccionada en el mismo, pero esta lista la cargo manual, no viene de ninguna tabla. Como haria? Creo un array en el cotrolador y los paso como?... uff de verdad esto lo pregunto una vez y jamas de nuevo, jejeje

Comment: Ah no, condicion corporal es otro campo en la tabla YEGUAS que no especifique para no alargar la info... En el form para registrar yeguas hay un select con valores precargados: Delgada, Normal y Robusta. Por ejemplo, al guardar en la tabla YEGUAS y asignar segun el select el valor "Delgada" al campo condicion_corporal y yo quiero que al ingresar al form para editar haga lo mismo que con el select cliente, esta vez como haria para evaluar el 'value' del select con el campo condicion_corporal para que quede seleccionado???

Comment: Exacto, condicion_corporal es un string. La tabla es la misma anterior con dicho campo::
    *YEGUAS*
    | id
    | cliente_id
    | nombre
    | edad
    | condicion_corporal

Comment: Y el select es este:                                                                                      ´<select class="form-control" id="condicion_corporal" name="condicion_corporal" required>
<option value="">Seleccione una Condición Corporal</option>
<option value="Delgada">Delgada</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="Robusta">Robusta</option>
</select>´

Comment: Escribí una respuesta, pues se hizo muy largo para los comentarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, paso a paso. En primer lugar, veo que desde el controlador estas devolviendo la vista solo con la variable `$yegua`, entonces, deberías devolver otra variable con los clientes para hacer el `@foreach` sobre `$clientes`. Algo así:

```
public function edit_yegua($id){ 
    $yegua = Yegua::findOrFail($id); 
    $clientes = Cliente::select('id', 'nombre')->get(); 
    return view('app.yeguas.edit_yegua',compact('yegua', 'clientes')); 
}
```

Luego en la vista, no tienes una variable `$cliente_id`, por lo que tendrías que obtener ese valor de la variable `$yegua`. Algo así:

```
@foreach ($clientes as $cliente) 
    <option value="{{$cliente->id}}" 
        @if( (int) $cliente->id === (int) $yegua->client_id) selected='selected' @endif
    > {{$cliente->nombre}} </option> 
@endforeach
```

---

Para el caso del select 'condicion_corporal', tendrás que poner la condición en cada option, pues los valores están hardcodeados:

```
<select class="form-control" id="condicion_corporal" name="condicion_corporal" required> 
    <option value="">Seleccione una Condición Corporal</option> 
    <option value="Delgada" @if($yegua->condicion_corporal === "Delgada") selected='selected' @endif >Delgada</option> 
    <option value="Normal" @if($yegua->condicion_corporal === "Normal") selected='selected' @endif >Normal</option> 
    <option value="Robusta" @if($yegua->condicion_corporal === "Robusta") selected='selected' @endif >Robusta</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Por qué día consultas? No sería más simple un join o aplicar eager loading para evitar ese if en el Select?

Comment: @Aprendiz no entendí tu pregunta... una consulta es sobre el modelo a editar y la otra es para llenar el select. El modelo a editar (Yegua) sólo va a tener su cliente relacionado, y el select requiere todos los clientes

Comment: Excelente amigo @porloscerrosΨ, ha sido de gran ayuda todo. Deberias dar clases jejeje... ahora a ver si me funciona **public function edit_yegua_action(Request $request)** jejeje pero ya ese es otro cuento. Se que son cosas básicas, tengo las ideas claras pero lo que tengo es que organizar bien la logica y por supuesto la sintaxis

Comment: Claro, puedes hacer otra pregunta si tienes problemas al guardar los datos. Y sería buena idea mejorar la lógica del campo 'condicion_corporal' para usar relaciones como lo hiciste con clientes, lo agregué a la respuesta como bonus de lo que surgió en los comentarios, pero asumo que ya sabes como hacerlo, pues lo hiciste con los clientes. Saludos.